# Vim yank from cursor position to end of nth line

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, nmap

I am trying to yank from my cursor posintion to end of nth line defined by a motion. So for the below text

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Donec non quam et erat pharetra 
venenatis in non erat.
```

When I have cursor on `dolor` in first line, I want to yank from `dolor` to `pharetra` on third line.

My first guess was `y2j` will give the desired result. But it gives the same result as `3yy` and it yanks the entire first line.

One alternate solution is to use `v$2jy`.

Is there a way to do equivalent of this in normal mode? Or remap `y{n}j` to `v${n}jy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `3y$` will do what you want.

If you followed the suggestion in `:help Y` and did `:map Y y$` you can use `3Y` as well. I'm mentioning this because it's a common mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Another version: from the beginning of `dolor`, `y/pharetra/e<CR>`